# Reading a CSV file in python yet having problem

Tags: csv, data-science

I have just started with Data Science and Machine learning. My problem is that I am not able to read a CSV file from the folder.`import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("C:\Users\HARISH S.G\Downloads")
data = pd.read_csv('Auto_Data_Preped.csv')
data.columns`

I have this error.

> (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

please help me with this.

Also, I am having trouble with PIP installation.

Comment: Is the result different in the read_csv() method if you use single quotes instead of double quotes? Looks like the error is interpreting the \U in \Users as an escape in an expandable string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using double backslashes instead? The backslash () character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character. (See https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).